# Django models.py migrate

Tags: django, django-models

I know that there are already a couple of threads about the migration/ makemigrations commands but none of them worked out for me, even after I reset the entire database with the flush command.

The error after I executed migrations is:

```
        `Exception Type:    OperationalError
         Exception Value: no such column: geruestproject_billing.id`
```

The weird thing is that the 0001.initial.py creates the class but adds the attribute via migrations.AddField. The code is posted below

```
initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Billing',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name_plural': 'Rechnungen',
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Client',
        fields=[
            ('Client', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ('Company_Name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='Firma')),
            ('Company_Email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='Firma Email')),
            ('Company_Phone', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, verbose_name='Telefon Firma')),
            ('Company_PostalCode', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=6, verbose_name='Postleitzahl')),
            ('Company_City', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, verbose_name='Stadt')),
            ('Company_Street', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, verbose_name='Strasse')),
            ('Contact_LastName', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='Nachname')),
            ('Contact_FirstName', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='Vorname')),
            ('Contact_Phone', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, verbose_name='Telefon Kontakt')),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name_plural': 'Kunden',
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Inventory',
        fields=[
            ('Item', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ('Name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('Price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, null=True, verbose_name='Preis in €')),
            ('Amount', models.IntegerField(default=1000)),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name_plural': 'Lager',
        },
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Project',
        fields=[
            ('Project', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ('Project_Amount', models.IntegerField(default=10)),
            ('Item', models.ForeignKey(on_delete='SET_NULL', to='geruestproject.Inventory')),
        ],
        options={
            'verbose_name_plural': 'Projekte',
        },
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='billing',
        name='invoice_client',
        field=models.ForeignKey(default='', on_delete='CASCADE', to='geruestproject.Client'),
    ),
]
```

My model is posted below (I deleted the irrelevant parts)

```
class Billing(models.Model):
      invoice_client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete = 'CASCADE', 
      blank = False, default = '')


    class Meta:
          verbose_name_plural = 'Rechnungen'


     import random, string
     def code_generator(size = 7, chars = string.digits):
           return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.invoice_number = code_generator()
        super(Billing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try running `manage.py sqlmigrate` to see if its generating the correct SQL for that table.

Comment: No it doesn't. It creates the model with 'id' first and then adds the field 'Add field invoice_client to billing' via ALTER TABLE.

Comment: it needs to add that field after it has created the model because it is a ForeignKey. That seems to suggest the migrations are being generated correctly. Do you have the `id` column in your database?

Comment: Isn't this id column automatically created by Django?

Answer (score 0):

A similar explanation is given here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#dependencies

Although the explanation given here is between two different apps, it's ***very similar*** to your condition:

> This means that when you run the migrations, the authors migration runs first and **creates the table the ForeignKey references, and then the migration that makes the ForeignKey column runs afterwards and creates the constraint**. If this didn’t happen, the migration would try to create the ForeignKey column without the table it’s referencing existing and your database would throw an error.

In your case, the **Billing** model is created before the **Client** model, hence the foreign key is added later.
Also observe that since your **Inventory** model is created before **Project** model, it *can* add the foreign key while creating the **Project** model.

The problem here is certainly in the order in which the tables are being created. With that said:

1. Delete all migration scripts under the migrations package except the **init**.py file.
2. Delete the database you are using.
3. `$ python3 manage.py makemigrations`
4. `$ python3 manage.py migrate`

That should solve the problem.